Braze Sdk integration with Flutter
I have tried to integrate Braze sdk in a flutter app, I have followed the documentation regarding the integration of the sdk in flutter but I still encountered a problem.
Error log:


"Early returning because the Braze instance isn't fully initialized. Always use Braze.getInstance(context) to get the latest Braze
instance. Please report to Braze if the issue continues.  Failed to
log custom event"
"Early returning because the Braze instance isn't fully initialized. Always use Braze.getInstance(context) to get the latest Braze
instance. Please report to Braze if the issue continues.  Failed to
set external id to: 6"


I am initializeing the braze plugin like this:
 braze = BrazePlugin();

using this instance I try to logCustomEvents and to use changeUser method.
Braze.getInstance(context)   does not exist in the flutter plugin.
Thank you!
Here is what I did to integrate the SDK:

created braze.xml file in the main/res/value folder

added the braze_plugin package to my pubspec.yaml


